# Cannot invoke "com.example.ChangeStreamExample.dao.EmpRepository.findbyempName(String)" because "this.empRepository" is null

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, jpa, spring-data-jpa

public class TestEmployee {
public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    AbstractEmployee employee = new AbstractEmployeeImpl();
    employee.callToUtil("Test1");

}
```

}

Comment: Hi, you definitely should give us more context. How your EmpRepository looks like? How do you run the application? Is spring context up or you are just running the main() above (which will not load spring beans for you, in particular the repository which could be, in turn, the reason of you NPE).